# Отправка и Проверка ответа из БД

Tags: php, html

Привет, я не силён в php  помогите исправить и довести код до ума .

У каждый страницы есть свои `$id_quest` и он совпадает из Базы данных (тоисть у нас есть ответ и мы проверяем если ответ совпадает с ответом из  БД ) и  если ответ совпадает с ответом из бд он  сохраняется в куки. пример в низу.

Таблица из Базы данных

```
CREATE TABLE `lesson`.`answer` ( 
`id` INT(11) NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
 `quest` VARCHAR(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ,

  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

код проверки

```
    <?php
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'lesson');
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $id_quest = 1;
            $user_quest = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, ($_POST['quest']));
            if(!empty($id_quest)) {
                $query = "SELECT  `quest`,`id_quest` FROM `answer` WHERE   id_quest = '$id_quest' AND quest = '$user_quest'";
                $data = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
                if(mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) {
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
                    setcookie('quest', $row['quest'], time() + (60*60*24*30));
                    header('Location: '.$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
                        }
                else {
                    echo 'Извините, вы должны ввести правильный ответ';
                }
            }

    }
        }

    ?>
```

заполнение формы

```
<?php if(empty($_COOKIE['quest'])) {
                            ?>  

            <form id="inputs" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">

            <h3>Ответ</h3>

            <input placeholder="Ответ" type="text" name="quest" size="98" ><br>
            <button  id="submit"  type="submit" name="submit">Отправка </button>

                            </form>
<?php
}
else {
?>
```

Всё правильно

```
<?php   
    }
    ?>
```

когда ответ положительный как сделать чтобы он отправил в другую таблицу эти данные

```
for(true){
        $name_quest = $_POST["name_quest"];
        $user_id = $_POST["user_id"];
        $query="INSERT INTO `fin` (`name_quest`, `user_id`) VALUES ('$name_quest','$user_id')"; 
        }
        <input type="hidden"  type="text" name="name_quest" value="exemple" >
        <input type="hidden"  name="user_id"   value="<?php echo $_COOKIE['user_id']; ?>"size="98" />
```

Comment: напишите в вопросе чем Вас Ваш код не устраивает и что работает не так, чтобы отвечающие могли быстрее Вам помочь.

Comment: В ошибке все написано. У Вас неопределена переменная `$dbc`. Где Вы открываете соединение с БД?

Comment: спс я не заметил что не поставил ево.